# Insert current logged on user's email address into script embeded on Sharepoint page

Tags: javascript, email, user

I have to login to another system from SharePoint. This is done by embeding a piece of javascript which redirects the user to the site, but must grab the current users email address to insert into the URL.

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://serko.au.stageandscreen.travel/SOLV2/JS/sso.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  generateSOLRedirectURL('https://serko.au.stageandscreen.travel', '<usersemailaddresshere>', 'secretkey');
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On SharePoint Online the userLoginName is his email address.

```
_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName
```

Comment: It's true for O365 accounts, but may be different if you authenticate via ADFS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following CSOM code to get email of current user.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var web = context.get_web()
var user = web.get_currentUser()
context.load(user)
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
  alert(user.get_email())
}, function () {
  alert('failed')
})
```

`context.executeQueryAsync` takes two functions - success handler and error handler. You can use first one to execute redirect.